# Check popup window status

Tags: javascript

When someone requests a chat, an entry is made in the database. I have an hidden iframe on our dashboard that checks the database every 20 seconds to see if there is a chat and if there is it launches a popup window. Even if the popup is open the iframe still refreshes the popup every 20 seconds. Want I am trying to achieve is a javascript to check the status of the popup. If it is closed I want it to reopen it... if it is open then it bring it into focus... but I dont want the popup to refresh.. as I have an ajax script doing this..

Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myOpenWindow(winURL, winName, winFeatures, winObj)
{
     var theWin;
     if (winObj != null)
     {
          if (!winObj.closed)
          {
               winObj.focus();
               return winObj;
          }
     }
     else
     {
          theWin = window.open(winURL, winName, winFeatures);
          return theWin;
     }
} 
</script>
<% IF ChatSessionID <> "" THEN %>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var gmyWin = null;
window.onload = function()
{
     var w = 900;
     var h = 500;
     var l = (screen.width-w)/2;
     var t = (screen.height-h)/2;
     var params = 'status=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',left=' + l + ',top=' + t;
     gmyWin = myOpenWindow("/chat/chat_window.asp?ChatSession=<%=ChatSessionID%>&id=3", "myWin", params, gmyWin)
}
</script>
<% END IF %>
```

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated..

Best Regards,
Paul

Comment: [window.closed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.closed) is a non-standard property, may or may not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I believe if you name the window (e.g. `myWin`) when you call window.open, then later call window.open again using the same name, it will return the existing window if its already open or open/re-open the window and return a handle to that.

### Edit

Ah, there you go -- from [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open):

> If a window with the name
>   strWindowName already exists, then,
>   instead of opening a new window,
>   strUrl is loaded into the existing
>   window. In this case the return value
>   of the method is the existing window
>   and strWindowFeatures is ignored.
>   Providing an empty string for strUrl
>   is a way to get a reference to an open
>   window by its name without changing
>   the window's location. If you want to
>   open a new window on every call of
>   window.open(), you should use the
>   special value _blank for
>   strWindowName.

I believe according to the above mentioned specs, this *might* work:

```
var hChatWindow = window.open("", "ChatWindow", "whatever features"); // url intentionally left blank
// hChatWindow now contains a reference to new, existing or re-opened window
hChatWindow.focus();
if (hChatWindow.location=="about:blank") {                            // not sure; you need to experiment here
    hChatWindow.location = "/chat/chat_window.asp?whatever";
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/GbnEL/show/), [source here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/GbnEL/).

Comment: Looks logical..  How would that fit into my existing framework..? as my javascript knowledge is kinda shaky..

Comment: I've added a demo. See if you can get it to work according to your needs.

Comment: @Aviral: sorry mate I was in the middle of editing my post and got freaked out when SO told me the post was edited. I've added the url to window.open documentation again.

Comment: This method worked after a little experimentation.  I had to put the main script in the parent window to ensure it worked correctly... Many thanks for your assistance.. One up for you!

Answer (score 0):

Register a callback on `gmyWin.onunload`.

Answer (score 0):

You will find it tricky to subvert "block pop-up windows" in most browsers. However, if it is disabled, the following will work.

Main window:

```
var status = false;

function winOpen(){
    window.open("child.html");
}

function winStatus(){
    alert(status);
}
```

Pop-up window:

```
window.opener.status = true;

window.onblur = window.focus;

window.onunload = function(){
    window.opener.status = false;
};
```